# WooCommerce Paypal Standard Gateway - IPN Received but order status stuck on 'processing'

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I have a Wordpress setup with WooCommerce using the standard Paypal Gateway. Payments are being received and going through fine. Paypal IPN is being received by the site and marked as "Completed" for an order, but the order status remains unchanged in WooCommerce and still reads as "Processing".

```
10-04-2016 @ 11:04:18 - Received valid response from PayPal
10-04-2016 @ 11:04:18 - Found order #1303
10-04-2016 @ 11:04:18 - Payment status: completed
```

[image: woocommerce order status]

**Other things entered into Paypal gateway settings:**

- Paypal API Details
- Paypal Identity Token
- Clients Paypal login email as the receiver email and paypal email
- Payment set to capture

**Paypal Return URL:**

- http://[URL]/checkout/order-received/

**Paypal Notification URL:**

- http://[URL]/?wc-api=WC_Gateway_Paypal

**Other Related Woo Plugins installed:**

- https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/
- https://woocommerce.com/products/smart-coupons/

---

I'm a little stumped as what else to try, as the IPN is obviously being recieved but for whatever reason the WooCommerce is not updating the order status with this information. There are some PHP Notices regarding unrelated points in other templates but not anything that should be interfering with WooCommerce. Any help or ideas to try would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, I did see the auto complete plugin but the client In hand required this to be a manual method. I managed to figure out a method that works for Paypal standard payment, based off the below resource:

http://codecharismatic.com/run-your-own-damn-code-after-paypal-calls-woocommerce-back/

```
<?php
/**
* Auto Complete Woocommerce 'processing' orders
*/

add_action( 'valid-paypal-standard-ipn-request', 'handle_paypal_ipn_response', 50, 1 );

function handle_paypal_ipn_response( $formdata ) {

    if ( !empty( $formdata['invoice'] ) && !empty( $formdata['custom'] ) ) {

        if( $formdata['payment_status'] == 'Completed' ) {

            // decode data
            $order_data = json_decode($formdata['custom'], true);

            // get order
            $order_id = ($order_data) ? $order_data['order_id'] : '';
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

            // got something to work with?
            if ( $order ) {

                if ($order->post->post_status == 'wc-processing'){

                    // Status success
                        WC_Gateway_Paypal::log( 'Changing order #' . $order->id . ' status from processing to completed');
                      $order->update_status( 'completed' );

                } else {

                    // Status fail
                        WC_Gateway_Paypal::log( 'Status fail, order #' . $order->id . ' status is set to ' . $order->post->post_status . ', not processing');

                }

            } else {

                // Order fail
                    WC_Gateway_Paypal::log( 'Fail, no order found');

            }

        } else {

            // Payment fail
                WC_Gateway_Paypal::log( 'Payment status fail, not completed');

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and discovered this is probably normal for WooCommerce since the product is supposed to be shipped out and then set to Completed. You can use a plugin to autocomplete the orders.

**WooCommerce Autocomplete Orders**
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-autocomplete-order/

**How To Automatically Set WooCommerce PayPal Orders as Completed**
http://biostall.com/how-to-automatically-set-woocommerce-paypal-orders-as-completed/

Note: You have to make sure your product is Virtual and set the Mode to "Paid orders of virtual products only" under WooCommerce > Settings > Extra Options